# Creating REST service using apache CXF in spring MVC

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, rest, cxf

Hello guys I am new to Spring MVC and i want to create a REST web service using Apache CXF...I have seen many tutorials online but I am so much confused with the annotations and all..Is there a simple neat and clean tutorial to refer
thanks

Comment: I think you need to learn everything you've mentioned step by step: you can't have "Learn Chinese language in-5-days tutorial". If you feel lack of knowledge with annotations – start with that. Then take Spring, then REST. Learn by looking examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is already using Spring MVC, I wouldn't try to create a web service with CXF. Just use the REST-style annotations that Spring MVC provides, and you'll get most (probably all) the way there. And it will integrate with other parts of your webapp which are using Spring a little more tightly.

Answer (score 1):

The best tutorials for Spring MVC (Beginners), i recommend http://www.vaannila.com/.

Another good one is http://www.javacodegeeks.com.

Just go through the links. Start from Hello World and keep doing practice.

Enjoy Coding.....

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's all right to be confused at first. You say there are many tutorials and you need one of them. Tutorials are great, but I'd recommend to look for books, not just for short descriptions. If you are new to Spring, try "Spring in Action" or any other, that would give you a basic understanding of what's going on in the tutorials.

Comment: thanks for replying but still would recommend any link to some online tutorial?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/writing-a-service-with-spring.html What about this one? My point is that tutorials give you nothing more then working little programs, but it's not enough if you don't have any background knowledge. The link I've just copied leads to the `cwiki.apache.org`, but I bet all the tutorials you saw in some blogs are pretty good from the point of view of those who created them. I think, this fact should show the fecundity of looking for just the right tutorial.